# MKMapSnapshotter startWithCompletionHandler never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapsnapshotter

Is there any reason why the completion handler on MKMapSnapshotter's startWithCompletionHandler method would not get called back? (not even with error!!)

I'm not doing anything fancy, just grabbing a snapshot and displaying it, all in the foreground, no background processing.

What's unusual is that it seems totally random, meaning sometimes it works just fine, other times it never does.

Here's my code:

```
MKMapSnapshotOptions *options = [[MKMapSnapshotOptions alloc] init];
options.size = somePredeterminedSize;
options.scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
options.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
options.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mycoordinate, 1000, 1000);

MKMapSnapshotter *snapshotter = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions:options];
[snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"[Error] %@", error);
        return;
    }

    MKAnnotationView *pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:nil reuseIdentifier:nil];
    pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map-pin"];
    UIImage *image = snapshot.image;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, YES, image.scale);
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    CGPoint point = [snapshot pointForCoordinate:self.bureau.coordinate];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point)) {
        point.x = point.x + pin.centerOffset.x - (pin.bounds.size.width / 2.0f);
        point.y = point.y + pin.centerOffset.y - (pin.bounds.size.height / 2.0f);
        [pin.image drawAtPoint:point];
    }

    UIImage *compositeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}];
```

I have tested this on several devices simultaneously each running different iOS versions:
iPhone 5S running iOS 8.4
iPhone 6 running iOS 9.2
iPhone 6+ running iOS 8.2

All 3 devices are connected to the same WIFI. The iPhone 6+ almost never fails while the iPhone 6 almost always does.

Any suggestions?

Comment: where that code is placed ? show the method and how it's called

Comment: try to call above code 'later'

Comment: also try to make 'snapshotter' a member of class, maybe it got released before doing it's job

Comment: thanks. Just tried that. Moved my code to viewDidAppear and set my MKMapSnapshotter object as a strong property. Still failing...

Comment: Hmm, try even later, fire a timer after 5 seconds view is showed on screen. I was working with MKMapSnapshotter last year until iOS9 was released and haven't any trouble with it, tested both on iOS8 and iOS7.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue,
in my app i have a list of addresses with some map images , and if you press on the image one of the options is to open it in the Maps App.
On the iPhone it created the images perfectly but on the iPad it didn't until i tried to open the address in the Apple "Maps" App (with MKMapItem.openMapsWithItems ...), it opened the Maps App and presented an alert for permissions , i pressed "Allow" , got back to my App and it started working perfectly.

Try to open the Maps App , allow permissions , and see if it work in your app.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I have this sometimes as well. My theory is that the "tile server" (or whatever daemon is responsible for downloading the map tiles) has crashed in that case. (Even the `MKMapView` instances I used did not show any tiles)

Rebooting the device always fixes it for me.

Comment: +1 for restarting the device. While its not the best solution, this is something we can tell our users if they are experiencing this issue.

Comment: I have struggled with this for days with the mapSnapshotter not loading the maps as it is supposed to, but I could see it is working on my other devices and I thought for a picosecond that it might be something with my developer certificates. But simply restarting my device works perfectly.